# Yosemite Server SMB Browsing

Tags: macos, server.app, smb, afp

Been experiencing endless issues with file sharing on Yosemite server and latest Server App (5.0.x).
When a user connected to the server in the finder sidebar, it connects with SMB and they experience issues. Like read only, etc..
So, AFP is the answer... Command + K (Connect to server) and enter the server IP prefixed with afp:// works fine. However, in attempted to make it easier for the user, I would like them to use the sidebar in finder.
If I turn OFF SMB for a particular share in file sharing in the server app, the share is no longer visable.
Has anyone experienced the same issue?
I assume the SMB only wants to work with bonjour?
Can I make the default bonjour browsing use AFP?

Thanks

Comment: SMB and AFP work without bonjour if you have the server IP. Bonjour just broadcasts the host's name to other devices. I have noticed poor SMB performance both when hosting on OS X server and when browsing from OSX to Linux and Windows shares. I have also noticed that some devices won't recognize the SMB share at all when hosted on OS X server. After googling around, I have discovered that others experienced this problem starting in Mavericks when Apple rolled their own SMB2.